# Editor saving file content in one line

Tags: php, netbeans, filezilla

I'm working on a project in PHP using Netbeans on Windows, when I send the file to the server using Filezilla all line breaks disappeared and everything is on one line. So I have several errors caused by single-line comments "/ /".
.
I wonder how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Transfer is Auto by default, you should change it to Binary. Don't forget to restart filezilla to be sure.